# Custom SEO friendly link

Tags: php, url, joomla, seo, components

I have a link custom link :

http://www.snopedia.com/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=listcats&cat_id=116&Itemid=&rsid=39

It show the list of resort in a country. rsid is the id of the country. I want to see the
url that display only the name of the country. Like: http://www.snopedia.com/BritishColumbia

So that would be the Htaccess rule I have to apply please tell me. Also I have to send those parameter on the other page like: task=listcats, cat_id=116, Itemid=, rsid=39

Thank, waiting for your reply:

Answer (score 1):

Hi You have change it from Joomla Administrator.

1. Login to Joomla Administrator
2. Goto Site => Global Configuration => Site
3. You can see  `SEO Settings` from right side of the page.
4. In that settings you have to change `Search Engine Friendly URLs` option to  Yes.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am using Joomla 1.1 . Its not having such option.

Comment: Update it to the latest version then.

Comment: Any other way to do it only by .htaccess, because its not a small site, its too big , more than 1.5 GB data in their and I can't update the custom component that I created. I have to change lots of coding stuff to make it in the higher version

Comment: Please give me any other suggestion .

Comment: Refer this link http://bodvoc.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45:modifying-your-joomla-htaccess-file&catid=2:joomla-security&Itemid=3

Comment: I have this configuration already setup, but I need the code.

Comment: If you have a 1.5GB site that you have 1.5GB of vulnerable areas thus you should upgrade to atleast 1.5.26, even if it takes some time. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247985/why-should-i-keep-my-joomla-version-up-to-date/12247989#12247989 . Im not sure where one would find a SEF extension for Joomla 1.1 as it's very old and not supported anymore