# After updating Joomla version "Media Manager" in Administrator panel not working

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

"My site is still on the old legacy Joomla platform but I did an update last week, which I probably shouldn't have done since everything was working fine. After the update I checked several features and all appeared to be operating properly. Then a week or so later I went back to add a photo to the **Media Manager** and now it times out and I get an error message." - (Unknown)

Its diverting me to the following page: **http://www.my-site.xxx/administrator/index.php?option=com_media**

and on this page the following error is coming: "**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/theaarc/public_html/libraries/joomla/filesystem/folder.php on line 506**"

Here is the Image:
[image: Error Image]

Comment: Try taking a backup of your site and upgrading to the Joomla 2.5 series as it's a more stable and secure version with a load more features that might interest you.

Comment: what was your previous version? Joomla 1.0?

Comment: @Lodder: Thanks for the tip but I already late now. I updated previously without backup, actually I'm new to Joomla. Did any way to revert Joomla to its previous version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a backup of your previous site before the upgrade, Im afraid reverting won't be possible else extremely hard and time consuming. Take a backup of the current website you have and try upgrading to Joomla 2.5, using [jUpgrade](http://redcomponent.com/redcomponent/jupgrade).

I explained on this Stackoverflow post, why it is important to ensure your Joomla version is up to date.

[Why should I keep my Joomla version up to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247985/why-should-i-keep-my-joomla-version-up-to-date/12247989#12247989)

Once done, check if the Media Manager is working.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Let me try. I will let you know soon!

Comment: @DawoodButt - The jUpgrade link lead to the incorrect page before, it's sorted now ;)