# Need to change the database password for my Joomla site

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Unfortunately today I got my Joomla 1.5 site hacked- the index.php has been overwritten and I've found as well a php script which does something nasty with the config.php file. 
I've changed the FTP password, however since the config.php file contains as well the database user/password I'd like to change it as well. What is the right place to change it ? should I change it just in config.php or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the database password must be done via your hosting cPanel and then in the config.php.

Once you have done this, I would suggest upgrading to Joomla 2.5 as it is far more secure and has more features. You should also consider installing some security extensions. I answered a question regarding security which you can find in the link below:

[Joomla! 2.5.4 Hacked: Having trouble with diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036763/joomla-2-5-4-hacked-having-trouble-with-diagnosis/11037642#11037642)

Here is also another bit of information I added regarding why keeping your Joomla version up to date is a good idea, if you don't already:

[Why should I keep my Joomla version up to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247985/why-should-i-keep-my-joomla-version-up-to-date/12247989#12247989)

Hope this helps