# How can i migrate community builder from joomla 1.0 to joomla2.5

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, joomla2.5

I am migrating my site from joomla 1.0 to joomla 2.5 and facing a critical problem.

I'm using a component named community builder and as I'm getting that its tables field's name are different from the joomla 1.0 . Please can anyone help me and tell me how I can  migrate this component easily?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly migrate from Joomla 1.0 to 2.5, however I really can't understand why you are still running such an old version of Joomla.

You will firstly have to migrate to Joomla 1.5. More information on how to do this can be found at the following link:

http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable

Once done, ensure you are running 1.5.26, which is the latest release of the 1.5 series. You will then need to install JUpgrade which is a component that easily migrates your Joomla 1.5 sites to 2.5.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658

Please do note that the migration process only updates core files and extensions. It does not update 3rd party extensions, so you will need to install the version of the extension that is compatible with your Joomla version.

This is going to be a big process, so please also consider starting from scratch as it might turn out to be the easier option.

These might also come in handy for you:

- [Why should I keep my Joomla version up to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247985/why-should-i-keep-my-joomla-version-up-to-date/12247989#12247989)
- [Extensions to improve security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036763/joomla-2-5-4-hacked-having-trouble-with-diagnosis/11037642#11037642)

Hope this helps