# how to evaluate joomla 1.5 to be safe agenist hacking

Tags: joomla

I would like to know if there are effective penetration testing tool that help evaluating  our Joomla site: *"www.ous.edu.sd"* since we had experienced hacking last month.

Comment: You won't be able just take a scanner and safely evaluate whether your app is safe (acunetix scanner is very decent), the best way to ensure that you are safe is that you are using up to date release of the open source package and only modules and addons that have solid history of releases and are from verified developers. Other than you should watch one of many bugtrack and security sites for releases about the particular joomla version etc. There really isn't a foolproof way, anyone can inspect the open source application and manage to find a vulnerability,e.g.after a update etc...

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to prevent you current 1.5 site from being hacked, cause you'll fail. Get yourself upgraded as soon as you can. I answered a question a while back as to why keeping you Joomla site up to date is very important:

[Why should I keep my Joomla version up to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247985/why-should-i-keep-my-joomla-version-up-to-date/12247989)

If your site is purely just an information site, then I would suggest upgrading to Joomla 3.1. Joomla 3.2 will be out literally **very** soon aswell. The reason being is that even though Joomla 2.5 was liked a lot by developers, it will be coming to the end of it's life in the second quarter of 2014. Seems a long time away but when the time comes, upgrading could be a bit of hassle.

Please do bare in mind that upgrading to Joomla 3.0 will **not** upgrade your 3rd party extensions that you have installed and thus you will have to install Joomla 3.x compatible versions of them.

Regarding the anti hacking side of things, I explained a little in the link provided but will mention it here anyway. The 3 main extensions I would get are:

1. [Admin Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/14087)
2. [AdminExhile](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/15711)
3. [Saxum IP Logger](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/8946)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 1.5.26 was the last version of the 1.5 line. *It is end of life.* As mentioned previously the best defence is to keep your Joomla! installation up-to-date and to keep an eye on the [Joomla VEL](http://vel.joomla.org), which tracks extensions with issues.

Without going to commercial tools I'm not sure for Joomla! specifically. Ages ago we used OWASP Joomla! Security Scanner, ([wiki here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Joomla_Vulnerability_Scanner_Project)), but [the SourceForge repo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joomscan/) indicates it's not being updated anymore.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Joomla_Vulnerability_Scanner_Project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually prevent yourself from Hacking, all you can do is Secure your website from external attacks.

For joomla, I recommend you to upgrade your current core version is there is public exploits for core version 1.5.

Once you upgrade your Joomla version to the newest you will need to add some extra security to prevent further attacks like :

- A rise of a 0day on the newest core joomla Versions.
- a symlink attack on Server which may lead on accessing your website database.
- added plugins to website which are vulnerable such as Contact us auto chat and such.

So what you need to do, is make your Administrator directory protected from unwanted visits. as nearly 95% of Forum / website template hacks are uploaded shells through Administrator panel. to do this all you need to do is make a txt file in the default www root folder and name it robots.txt and inside it you will need to write the dir that you dont want any user to access such as administrator, Example :

```
User-agent: /
Disallow: administrator/
```

You can also block any unwanted website crawlers to list your website contents and check for any vulnerabilities in it by adding this in your robots.txt

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

which will basically block any access to your website from user-agent ia-archiver, which is most likely what web crawlers use like Acunetix.

Answer (score 0):

I have encouraged all of my clients to upgrade from 1.5 to 2.5 or higher. Unfortunately, not all of them want to pay to do this and I dont have the time for free upgrades. The result is that the exploits that are available for 1.5 have left my entire server vulnerable and has been attacked several times over the last year. I have no other choice but to separate the 1.5 sites on to another box and tell the clients too bad so sad the next time they get hacked as I cannot afford to keep fixing them. as everyone above has stated, it is critical that you migrate from 1.5. There are plenty of extensions and tools available to assist you. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade it to Joomla 3.1, Joomla 1.5 is too easy to hack.