# file_put_contents errors in Joomla

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have a Joomla 1.5.20 site and I am not able to upload & update any file in it. The website is running on a Windows Webserver.

```
Warning: file_put_contents(D:\inetpub\vhosts\hidden\httpdocs\v1\administrator\cache/da4f9e501a6359708d714f016ef2d500.spc) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\vhosts\hidden.tld\httpdocs\v1\libraries\simplepie\simplepie.php on line 8666

Warning: D:\inetpub\vhosts\hidden.tld\httpdocs\v1\administrator\cache/da4f9e501a6359708d714f016ef2d500.spc is not writeable in D:\inetpub\vhosts\hidden.tld\httpdocs\v1\libraries\simplepie\simplepie.php on line 1779

Warning: file_put_contents(D:\inetpub\vhosts\hidden.tld\httpdocs\v1\administrator\cache/da4f9e501a6359708d714f016ef2d500.spc) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\vhosts\hidden.tld\httpdocs\v1\libraries\simplepie\simplepie.php on line 8666

Warning: D:\inetpub\vhosts\hidden.tld\httpdocs\v1\administrator\cache/da4f9e501a6359708d714f016ef2d500.spc is not writeable in D:\inetpub\vhosts\hidden.tld\httpdocs\v1\libraries\simplepie\simplepie.php on line 1779
```

I have tried deleting and recreating cache folder. Since it is a windows webserver I don't it a permission issue. Please advise me on how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide the code you're using?

Comment: I'm not using any code. This error is showing everywhere in the joomla admin and I am not able to upload/update any files in Joomla.

Comment: Using ftp, update to joomla 1.5.26 then add the security patch here https://github.com/PhilETaylor/Joomla1.5.999 or here http://anything-digital.com/blog/security-updates/joomla-updates/joomla-15-security-patch-made-easy-to-install.html . Joomla 1.5.26 and below suffer from great vulnerabilities that have been exposed for years

Comment: Thanks Riccardo. I was planning to update it as the site was hacked sometime back because of a vulnerability in JCE Editor.

Comment: @user3044450 - The exact reason why I wrote [>> this <<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247985/why-should-i-keep-my-joomla-version-up-to-date/12247989#12247989) and always have a go at people when they are not using an up to date version of their series ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your folder permissions:

1. Login to Administrator panel
2. Select **Help > System info** from top menu
3. Select tab **Directory Permissions**, all folders listed here need to have 'Writable' permissions.

If any of those folders are **Unwritable**, login to your server with ftp client, or cPanel, and change folder's CHMOD permissions to **755**

Comment: I have already mentioned that it is a Windows Webserver and there is no chmod in it. I have checked in system info and all permissions are fine.

Comment: @di3sel, folders should be set to 755, not 777, due to security issues